# After comparing two columns, how can I remove unique values in one column with its values in other different columns in R

Tags: r

I have 3 columns in an excel file.
Note: my DCL anc CL columns are not the same lenght. I have extra values in CL and also my values in CL have numeric values in ic50. Exactly I remove both those extra values which are in CL and ic50.  (DCL, CL and ic50 are my columns' names)

```
DCL         CL          ic50
COLO-684    COLO-684    1,853021
COLO-792    COLO-792    1,673109
COLO-824    COLO-824    24,194019
COLO-829    COLO-829    125,288504
COR-L105    COR-L105    1,324301
COR-L23     COR-L23     13,645992
CPC-N       COR-L311    3,807295
CTV-1       CP66-MEL    7,974192
CW-2        CPC-N       4,701374
D-263MG     CTV-1       0,252652
D-283MED    CW-2        6,857369
            D-263MG     17,863089
            D-283MED    0,279165
```

I want to remove unique values in colum CL with its values of column ic50. Finally, I want to have the values in both in DCL and CL with the numeric values of CL in ic50. So, I will have the same length in all columns.

Expected file:

```
DCL         CL          ic50
COLO-684    COLO-684    1,853021
COLO-792    COLO-792    1,673109
COLO-824    COLO-824    24,194019
COLO-829    COLO-829    125,288504
COR-L105    COR-L105    1,324301
COR-L23     COR-L23     13,645992
CPC-N       CPC-N       4,701374
CTV-1       CTV-1       0,252652
CW-2        CW-2        6,857369
D-263MG     D-263MG     17,863089
D-283MED    D-283MED    0,279165
```

Comment: Please paste your data into the question using `dput(your_data)`. It makes it easer to help you so data can be copied as an R object.

Comment: So you want to copy & paste the column CL into DCL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
dat <- tibble::tribble(~DCL,         ~CL,          ~ic50,
"COLO-684",   "COLO-684",   1.853021,
"COLO-792",    "COLO-792",     1.673109,
"COLO-824",   "COLO-824",   24.194019,
"COLO-829",    "COLO-829",     125.288504,
"COR-L105",   "COR-L105",   1.324301,
"COR-L23",     "COR-L23",      13.645992,
"CPC-N",     "COR-L311",   3.807295,
"CTV-1",       "CP66-MEL",     7.974192,
"CW-2",       "CPC-N",      4.701374,
"D-263MG",     "CTV-1",        0.252652,
"D-283MED",   "CW-2",       6.857369,
NA_character_,"D-263MG",     17.863089, 
NA_character_,"D-283MED",    0.279165)

left_join(dat %>% select(DCL), dat %>% select(-DCL) %>% mutate(DCL = CL)) %>% na.omit()
#> Joining, by = "DCL"
#> # A tibble: 11 × 3
#>    DCL      CL          ic50
#>    <chr>    <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 COLO-684 COLO-684   1.85 
#>  2 COLO-792 COLO-792   1.67 
#>  3 COLO-824 COLO-824  24.2  
#>  4 COLO-829 COLO-829 125.   
#>  5 COR-L105 COR-L105   1.32 
#>  6 COR-L23  COR-L23   13.6  
#>  7 CPC-N    CPC-N      4.70 
#>  8 CTV-1    CTV-1      0.253
#>  9 CW-2     CW-2       6.86 
#> 10 D-263MG  D-263MG   17.9  
#> 11 D-283MED D-283MED   0.279
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: As OP has empty cells I think they might also need something like this dat %>% mutate_all(., list(~na_if(.,""))) to get the NA's to be able to omit

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works:)
but Can we get the whole number of ic50 values. I mean, my first ic50 values in the first row is 1.853021. I need all numbers after comma, not only 1.85.

Comment: Those numbers are still there, the way the tibble prints is just with a smaller number of digits.  If you added `%>% as.data.frame()` after it, that would make it so you could see all the numbers.